# How to install windows on a logical partition created by ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, partition, hard-drive

When I try to install windows xp on `/dev/sda5` windows tell me that it can not write on `/dev/sda1`

How can I install windows xp on `/dev/sda5` without messing up some thing or is it not possible to install windows on this partition?

```
cfdisk (util-linux-ng 2.17.2)
Disk Drive: /dev/sda
Size: 250059350016 bytes, 250.0 GB
Heads: 240
Sectors per Track: 63
Cylinders: 32301

Name         Flags        Part Type      FS Type          [Label]    Size (MB)


sda1         Boot         Primary        Linux ext3                  25004.86
sda2                      Primary        Linux ext3                  125968.72
                                         Unusable                         0.41   *
sda3                      Primary        Linux ext3                   50708.53   *
                          Logical        Free Space                       0.61   *
sda5                      Logical        Linux ext3                   41568.43   *
sda6             NC       Logical        Linux swap / Solaris          1820.61   *
                          Logical        Free Space                    4984.12   *







 / _| __| (_) | ____| |_   _ _ __ ___  _ __  
| |_ / _` | | |/ / _` | | | | '_ ` _ \| '_ \ 
|  _| (_| | |   < (_| | |_| | | | | | | |_) |
|_|  \__,_|_|_|\_\__,_|\__,_|_| |_| |_| .__/ 
                                      |_|    


Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
240 heads, 63 sectors/track, 32301 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 15120 * 512 = 7741440 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x589cadc5

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  

    /dev/sda1   *           1        3230    24418768+  83  Linux
    /dev/sda2            3231       19502   123016320   83  Linux
    /dev/sda3           19503       26053    49520047+  83  Linux
    /dev/sda4           26053       32301    47239401    5  Extended
    /dev/sda5           26053       31422    40594129+  83  Linux
    /dev/sda6           31423       31658     1775616   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Mind you `/dev/sda5`, `/dev/sda5`, `/dev/sda5` are under `/dev/sda4` as logical partition since `dev/sda4` is of file

Comment: Don't confuse "logical volume" and "logical partition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP, SP2 or higher, can be installed onto a logical partition, but its bootloader must be [on a primary partition](http://www.sousuke.org/wiki/Installing_Windows_on_a_logical_partition).

Comment: what if i deleted all the partitions contained in /dev/sda4 i mean it self too(ie. /dev/sda4 ) but then i should be able to install it but that also have a problem b/se the empty space shuld be moved up into the middle or start of the /dev/sda so that windows should detect it can you help me with that @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 0):

Your problem actually is that the partition is in ext3 format, which Windows can't read.  It must be in NTFS format.